# How to save customized color tables in DigitalMicrograph GMS 2.x

Tags: dm-script

After updating DigitalMicrograph from GMS 1.x to  GMS 2.x, customized color tables can not be saved. Anyone knows how to save a customized color table under DigitalMicrograph GMS 2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not necessarily a scripting question, but it can be solved via scripting. It actually appears to be a bug in DigitalMicrograph version GMS 2.x.  Custom colour tables are stored at the file location

```
C:\Users\_USERNAME_\AppData\Local\Gatan\ColorTables\
```

You can get at this directory path using the command:

```
GetApplicationDirectory("user_color_table",0)
```

Since GMS 2.x, colour tables are stored with the file format *.dm4. Unfortunately, the drop-down list of custom colour tables only lists file entries of the format *.dm3. (Clearly a bug.)
To make it work again, save the colour-table *twice* in that folder. Once with the *.dm3 extension, and once with the *.dm4 extension.

You could use the following script to store the colour table of an existing image under a custom name:

```
Image img 
if ( !GetFrontImage( img ) ) exit( 0 )
Image CLUT := img.ImageGetImageDisplay( 0 ).ImageDisplayGetInputColorTable()
String path = GetApplicationDirectory( "user_color_table" , 1 ) 
String name
If ( !GetString( "Enter name", img.GetName(), name ) ) exit( 0 )

CLUT.SaveAsGatan( PathConcatenate( path , name ) )    // Save as DM4
CLUT.SaveAsGatan3( PathConcatenate( path , name ) )   // Save again as DM3
```

Note that you can also use a script to set specific color tables for images instead of using stored/named ones. See example:

Create a color lookup table (CLUT) as 16x16 RGB image:

```
RGBImage CreateCLUT()
{
  image r1, g1, b1
  number nr, ng, nb, x, y, i, j, count 
  r1 = IntegerImage( "r", 4, 0, 16, 16 )
  g1 = IntegerImage( "g", 4, 0, 16, 16 )
  b1 = IntegerImage( "b", 4, 0, 16, 16 )
  for ( j = 0; j < 16; j++ ) for( i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
  {
    count = I * 16 + j
    nr = 0; ng = ( 255 - count ) * 4;  nb = ( count - 191 ) * 4;
    if ( count <= 191 )
    {
      nr = ( 191 - count ) * 4;  ng = 255; nb = ( 191 - count ) * 4;
    }
    if ( count <= 127 )
    {
      nr = 255;  ng = ( count - 63 ) * 4; nb = ( count - 63 ) * 4;
    }
    if ( count <= 63 )
    {
      nr = 255; ng = 255 - count * 4;  nb = 0;
    }
    SetPixel( r1, j, i, nr )
    SetPixel( g1, j, i, ng )
    SetPixel( b1, j, i, nb )
  }
  return rgb( r1, g1, b1 ) 
}
```

Set a CLUT image to an image. (Ensure it is displayed as RasterDisplay first.):

```
Number SetClut( Image img, Image CLUT )
{
  if ( !img.ImageIsValid() ) return 0
  if ( 0 == img.ImageCountImageDisplays() ) return 0
  ImageDisplay disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
  if ( 1 != disp.ImageDisplayGetDisplayType() ) return 0
  disp.ImageDisplaySetInputColorTable( CLUT )
  return 1
}

image img
if ( !GetFrontImage( img ) ) exit( 0 )
SetClut( img, CreateCLUT() )
```

Comment: Works! Thanks BmyGuest